# Smallest data type - can I define a one bit variable?

Tags: c, types

I need only one bit to represent my data - 1 or 0. What is the best way to do so in C? The "normal" data types are too large.

Comment: Is memory so scarce that you need to store values as individual bits? What are you using it for? Maybe there's a better way.

Answer (score 31):

You could create

```
typedef struct foo
{
    unsigned x:1;
} foo;
```

Where you have told the compiler that you'll only be using one bit of `x`.

But due to structure packing arrangements (the C standard is intentionally flexible in order that compilers can optimise according to the machine architecture), it may well turn out that this still occupies as much space in memory as a regular `unsigned` and an array of `foo`s doesn't have to be bitwise contiguous.

Comment: would using `#pragma pack(1)` and `#pragma pack(0)` arround the struct avoid the packing arrangmenets you explained?

Answer (score 8):

If you don't need **millions** of these flags or have extremely limited memory constraints, the best way is definitively an `int`.

This is because an `int` normally corresponds to the natural word size of your platform and can, properly aligned, be accessed quickly. The machine reads a word at a time anyways and using the single bits requires masking and shifting, that costs time. On your typical PC with gigabytes of RAM, this would be just silly.

If memory consumption **really** is an issue, there are bitfield structures.

Comment: Masking and shifting take 0.5 - 1 cycle. Adding an int could take you over an alignment boundary and increase the memory footprint, significantly.

Answer (score 6):

If you really want, you can create a structure with a member variable , [bit-fielded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) to 1 bit.

Remember, the data type of the member variable needs to be `unsigned`, as you need to store `0` and `1`.

Answer (score 4):

The portable way is the definition of a variable which individual bits are used as flags.

```
    #define FLAG_FOO 0
    #define FLAG_BAR 1

    // in case platform does not support uint8_t
    typedef unsigned char uint8_t;

    uint8_t flags;

    void flag_foo_set()
    {
        flags |= (1 << FLAG_FOO);
    }

    void flag_foo_clr()
    {
        flags &= ~(1 << FLAG_FOO);
    }

    uint8_t flag_foo_get()
    {
        return flags & (1 << FLAG_FOO);
    }
```

While this can seem superfluos compared to C bit fields. It is portable to basically every ANSI C compiler.

Comment: Very pedantically, does `uint8_t` **have** to be supported by *every* ANSI C compiler? I'm not completely sure. `unsigned char` might be a better choice.

Comment: No, the uintX_t types are only required by C99 -- for full portability, use `unsigned char`

Comment: `typedef unsigned char uint8_t;` seems potentially dangerous to me.

Comment: Why is that, Bathsheba? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the smallest addressable chunk of data in C is a byte. You can not have a pointer to a bit, so you can not declare a variable of 1 bit size. But as Sourav Ghosh already pointed out, you can declare bitfields, where one bit is accessed directly.